# My sql query to retrieve only duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have a table named '**entity**' in DB which consists of

id, 
entityname, 
created time, 
modified time.

I want to retrieve only records which have duplicate entries like if there are two entities with name Arthur then i want only that two records.
I couldn't construct the query as comparing entityname with entity name is returning me all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM entity 
WHERE entityname IN 
(SELECT entityname 
 FROM entity 
 GROUP BY entityname 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: @Sangram : my query displays all duplicate records.. (not just name & count)

Comment: how many records are there in your entity table? Did you put ; at the end?

Comment: 7k is not a big number and this should work fine. You can try the following query as well:  
    SELECT entity . * 
FROM entity, 
(
SELECT entityname
FROM entity
GROUP BY entityname
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
)tmp
WHERE tmp.entityname = entity.entityname

Answer (score 0):

This will select all  entityName and RecordCount

```
 Select entityName, count(*) as RecordCount
 from entity
 group by entityName
```

where unique entityName RecordCount = 1

Then to select all records with duplicates:

```
 Select entityName, count(*) as  RecordCount
 from entity
 group by entityName
 having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanx for the query guys, but its displaying the entityName and its count, can we  construct the query such that it displays even the duplicate records. Like there are 4 entity by name Arthur but their id is different, so can the query return all four entities.